# Color box not showing Tiff images in my php program

Tags: php, css, image, web, colorbox

In my program I can not view tiff file by using color box,I am developing website using php codelgniter framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll probably be due to browser support of the TIFF format.

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support for supported file types.

Answer (score 0):

If imagemagic is installed on your server (most unix hosts have it) its as simple as ...

```
<?php
$exec = "convert /path/to/file.tiff /path/to/file.jpg";
exec($exec, $yaks);
//to view any errors >> // print_r($yaks);
?>
```

or

```
$image = new Imagick('something.tiff');
$image->setImageFormat('png');
echo $image;
```