# Colorbox not rendering tiff image

Tags: colorbox, tiff

Inside of a Colorbox overlay, I have an img tag pointing to a TIFF image. The image doesn't load at all. I've read [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411978/color-box-not-showing-tiff-images-in-my-php-program) wherein someone blamed the browser's inability to handle the image format. But when I open another tab that points directly to the image, the browser manages to render it.

How can I get the image to correctly render in Colorbox?

Comment: Some code would go a long way toward helping us help you.
Aside from that, is there a specific reason you /must/ have a TIFF on a web page? TIFF is not exactly a bandwidth-friendly format, after all...

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful to know things like what browser and OS you were testing on.